# Linking socket.io file to startup file node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have my start up file and I linked a socket.io file to it, cause my socket.io file is too large it needed to be separate. Everything works good but I require my socket.io file on connection, and I would only like it to be called once instead of it being called every time a page is refreshed or some one goes to another page on my website.

I am looking for another way to require my socket.io file instead of on connection. Here is my code if someone could help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated.. Thank you for helping...

```
socketStart = server.listen(8081, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8081');

});
  
 let connectSocket;

 connectSocket = exports.connectSocket = require('socket.io')(socketStart);
 
 connectSocket.use(function(socket, next) {
    sessionWare(socket.request, socket.request.res, next);
 });
  
  connectSocket.on('connection', require('./socketServer.js'));
```